# Netlify Deployment Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Tags: deployment, request, netlify, access-control

I have [this react app](https://github.com/havriutkin/weather-react-app) on my git.

I am trying to use Netlify to deploy it, but API request doesn't work with Access-Control-Allow-Origin error.

[image]

I have been trying to find a solution on Netlify forums. I found few that suggested adding configuration using `netlify.tomb` or `_headers` files. I tried both - doesn't work. You can check configs that are written in those files on my git repo (link provided above). Besides, I changed from http to https - and it didn't give any results.
Does anyone have any idea how to fix it?